# TCL Formatting Woes

Tags: tcl

```
# My first application for reals!
set drink {{"Kiwi Juice"} {"Apple Juice"} {"Pumpkin Juice"} {"Soda"}}
set price {{1.50} {0.50} {2.00} {1.25}}
foreach c $drink b $price {
    set price1 [format "%-10s %+20s " "Drink" "Price"]

    set price2 [format "%-5s %+10d Dollars " $c $b]

    puts $price1
    puts $price2
}
```

It won't run. Apparently it always stops at the `$c $b` part, but I'm sure I did it right!

Comment: What is your expected output? Also, I get the error `expected integer but got "1.50"` in my shell, indicating that you need `%+10f` instead of `%+10d` (`f` meaning float).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%d` substitution in `format`, of which `%+10d` is a specialization, *only works with integers*. `1.50` isn't an integer, it's a floating-point number (or a string, of course). You probably want the `%f` substitution, specifically `%+10.2f` (2 decimal places, overall width 10, with sign):

```
set drink {{"Kiwi Juice"} {"Apple Juice"} {"Pumpkin Juice"} {"Soda"}}
set price {{1.50} {0.50} {2.00} {1.25}}
foreach c $drink b $price {
    set price1 [format "%-15s %+10s " "Drink" "Price"]
    set price2 [format "%-15s %+10.2f Dollars " $c $b]

    puts $price1
    puts $price2
}
```